# Async request recursively

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, recursion

I need to make a request to our API for check a flag in a record of our DB. I can make this request "n" times maximum. If I don't find a correct value, I will return an error.

I have tried to use JQuery attribute `async:false` to make an async request synchronous with no effect (and I have seen that is deprecated).

Another option was to make an AJAX request recursively, but AJAX caches the value. I have used `cache:false` with no effect too.

I am looking for other alternatives (node libraries, patterns, ...) but with no luck until the moment.

Someone has solved a similar problem?

**UPDATE 1:** My last code with recursive call

```
function checkPay(initialResponse, attempts){
if (attempts == 50){
    console.log("Something goes wrong after 50 attempts...");
    console.log("Let's restart and try again");
} else {
    ajax.jsonRequest('get', 'check_pay', {transactionID: "123FOO"}) //A simple wrapper for $.ajax
        .done(function(responseStatus){
            if (responseStatus.status == "PENDING"){
                console.log("Still waiting...");
                checkPay(initialResponse, attempts + 1);
            } else if (responseStatus.status == "ACCEPTED"){
                console.log("Yuhuu!!!");                    
            } else if (responseStatus.status == "REJECTED") {
                console.log("Ooops...");                    
            } else {
                console.log("Wat?");
            }
        }).fail(function(error){
            console.log("ERROR", error);
            return "REJECTED"
        });
}
```

}

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: @AxelAmthor post updated with code ;)

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: to avoid caching you could add a GET parameter with a random value, like `'?d='+(+new Date)`

Comment: This may be out of context, but I hope you are aware that you could replace this logic with `socket.io`. So instead of polling so frequently, you could push back from server as soon as the data is available.

Comment: Thanks @Hacketo, it works! :)

Comment: @Салман thanks! I have not worked with `socket.io` and I don't know that could do this functionality. In future versions, maybe I willl try it :)

Comment: Alright, btw, you're firing 50 consecutive requests without any delay. Looking at the code, it seems you're checking approval of a payment user just made. It is a critical piece and killing the server like this isn't good. Man! you really need to switch to socket.io.

Comment: Yeah, I know @Салман! I have check socket.io and looks that is THE SOLUTION. But I can't add a library until my manager accepts it. Now we are next to deadline, so I am pretty sure that my manager won't accept this change, ha ha. I am trying to add `settimeout(function(){return true;}, 1000)` to delay the request. I know that is not the best solution, but will fix the problem until next version...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent caching by adding a pseudo-random parameter to every request. The browser and your server will believe that because your request contains different query data, that you may be asking for different information and will not serve a cached response.

You should simply be able to change

```
ajax.jsonRequest('get', 'check_pay', {transactionID: "123FOO"})
```

To:

```
ajax.jsonRequest('get', 'check_pay', {
  transactionID: "123FOO",
  timestamp: Date.now()
})
```

Comment: `Date.now` return the number of milliseconds since 1970. The `Math.random` part is useless, or OP makes requests quicker than 1000/sec

Comment: The intent was to prevent multiple clients from potentially having the same time. However, those should probably be cached anyway as the point is to poll until the service is available.

Comment: It works!! First of all it didn't work and after study out ajax library, I see that we cache the promise and return it... now fix it and works nice! Thanks @rrowland